# Does Google Forms have two versions: consumer (@gmail.com) and Google Apps for Work versions?

Tags: google-workspace, google-forms

I have to build Google Form integrations to migrate data from a form and make changes to email, calendar, contacts, sheet and drive (all Google apps).

I am getting results for Google Apps for Work and the consumer Google Forms but not two versions of the api.

Are there two such versions of the form and their separate APIs or is there just one?

Comment: By "simple vanilla" are you referring to Google Forms created using a consumer Gmail account? In other words, an accounts with an @gmail.com address?

Comment: @Folk Yes the one with at-gmail.com address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, referring to the Forms Service in Google Apps Script, I see no indication that there are two APIs for forms.

Reference: [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/)

Answer (score 3):

[Google Apps Scripts](http://www.google.com/script/start) have only one [Form service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) that works both for consumer accounts (with or without a gmail.com email address) and for Google Apps for Works and similar accounts.

The difference is that some features, like [setCollectEmail(collect)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setCollectEmail(Boolean)), are only available for Google Apps for Work and similar accounts, the [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) are not same, and perhaps other differences, but most of the classes, methods and enums are the same.

Comment: Please post a new question including enough details to understand what do you mean by "integration script", etc.